# JavaScript Math to PHP Page ID

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a form that takes a birthdate, adds up all the digits, then uses the result to query the database and display the results. The sum has to be a number between 1 an 22 in order for it to choose from the database.

I have the form button to trigger the function getBirthCard, but on click it simply spits the value of the form inputs into the URL.

Can anyone give me an idea of what's not coded properly in order for this to work? Please and thank you!

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function getBirthCard() {
    var month = lpn.month.value;
    var day = lpn.day.value;
    var Byear = lpn.year.value;
    var century = Byear.substring (0,2);
    var year = Byear - century*100;
    sum = parseInt(day) + parseInt(month) + parseInt(century) + parseInt(year);

    reduce();

    results(sum);
 }

 function reduce(){

 var first; // first one or two digits
 var last; // last digit

 var sumStr = "" + sum;

 // while number is bigger than 22
 while (sum > 22) {
    // if it is a three digit number
    if (sum > 99) {
        first= sumStr.substring(0,2);
        last= sumStr.substring(2);
        sum = parseInt(first) + parseInt(last);
        sumStr = "" + sum;

    // if it is a two digit number
    } else {
        first= sumStr.substring(0,1);
        last= sumStr.substring(1);
        sum = parseInt(first) + parseInt(last);
        sumStr = "" + sum;
    }
 } // end while

} // end reduce   


}
function results()
    {
    window.location.assign("http://arcanabazaar.com/results.php?id=' + sum")

    }

</script>
```

Here's the form that I'm using:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" name="lpn" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="month" name="month" placeholder="08">
<input type="text" id="day" name="day" placeholder="20">
<input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="1987">
<br><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="getBirthCard()" class="btn btn-large">What's My Card?</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're choosing a card from the major arcana based on the birthday digits. If you don't care too much about how this is calculated, here's a quick way to do it using modular arithmetic:

```
function getBirthCard() {
    var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
    var sum = parseInt(month) + parseInt(day) + parseInt(year);

    var card = sum % 22 + 1; // this is always from 1 to 22

    window.location.assign('http://arcanabazaar.com/results.php?id=' + card);
    return false;
 }
```

The button to call this must be coded as:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return getBirthCard();" class="btn btn-large">What's My Card?</button>
```

The OnClick event must return false, so that it doesn't continue to actually submit the form. That's why it was sending the month, day, year values directly previously.

This will give different results than your code was intending, but perhaps this will suffice.

(EDIT: Replaced lpn.month.value by document.getElementById("month").value etc.)
(EDIT2: Return false to onclick caller.)

EDIT3: Here's code to repeatedly add the digits together until they are less than or equal to 22:

```
function getBirthCard() {
    var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
    var card = getCardFromDate( month, day, year );
    window.location.assign('http://arcanabazaar.com/results.php?id=' + card);
    return false;
}

function getCardFromDate( month, day, year )
{
  var sum = parseInt('' + month + day + year);
  while( 22 < sum )
  {
    var digits = (''+sum).split('');
    sum = 0;
    for( var i=0 ; i<digits.length ; ++i ) sum += parseInt(digits[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's still just rewriting the URL with the values of the form inputs.

Comment: lpn.month.value etc. wasn't getting the form values correctly. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for helping Matt. It's still not working, though. I probably should have stuck with PHP. Not that I know how to do it in PHP, but this JavaScript is killing me.

Comment: I should have caught this earlier: the onlick event must have false returned to it. I tested this one directly and it works.

Comment: Yay!! Thank you, Matt!

Comment: Another quick question: Would this be the right way to go about splitting up the digits to add them:


`dayOne= day.substring(0,2);

        dayTwo= day.substring(2);
        day = parseInt(dayOne) + parseInt(dayTwo);`

Comment: How's that? New code adds the digits together until they are less than or equal to 22.

Comment: Omigod, Matt, omigod. You are the most awesomest person ever! Thank you sooo much.